# What is a good way for an app user-agent string looking like iPhone/Chrome/Whatever to most of the websites?

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, user-agent

We are making an iOS and Android app that has a webview as a part of its functionality. And when it views our own website, we like tuning the pages for the in-app view (e.g. we cut out header as app has its own chrome anyway). The rest of the web we show as is and.. here the problem comes.

We identify ourselves in user-agent string as "OurApp/0.9.24 (iPhone; iOS 6.1.2; Scale/2.00)")" that is similar to iPhone, but not exactly iPhone and some websites including www.google.com show as the desktop pages instead of a mobile optimized ones.

Has anybody had similar issues?
Any suggestions on how to make a user string that would identify our app yet will look like an iPhone to most of the web sites including www.google.com?

P.S.
Typical iPhone browser string looks like the following:
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A405"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the result you're seeing is expected.  Sites sniff the user-agent in order to determine how to display the content.  Essentially, you're creating an "unknown" agent as far as the rest of the world is concerned, so the default will typically be to show the desktop version.

Perhaps you can use a the default user-agent string but add something onto the end as an extension.  Check this out
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent_string#Format
and
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.43

Note the description of the last segment

> Mobile/7B405: This is used by the browser to indicate specific enhancements that are available directly in the browser or through third parties. An example of this is Microsoft Live Meeting which registers an extension so that the Live Meeting service knows if the software is already installed, which means it can provide a streamlined experience to joining meetings.

**Bottom line,** according to the spec you should be able to add "/product comment" to identify your product so in the case of the iPhone string **you would append "/0.9.24 OurApp" to the end rather than the beginning** and then sniff for that.

Comment: Yes, we should add our component as the last one then. Or since it's for our website only, go for a custom header as @ggmathur suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of sites have brittle user agent parsing, so you may want to tread lightly when tweaking it. I suggest appending an identifier such as `OurApp/0.9.24` at the end of the user agent - it's worked for me in the past.

Better yet, send a custom header identifying your app. I believe Android's Webview does this out of the box. It sends something like `X_REQUESTED=com.your.app`.

This is pretty straightforward to add in iOS as well, and will prevent 3rd party sites from messing up reading in your user agent.

Additionally, it'll prevent you from having to parse out a version number and what not from the user agent.

Comment: Yes, custom header would be a better solution probably (we actually use it anyway for the API calls, but not for the web side), but for now the quick fix is indeed to append our part of user-agent string to the end. Thanks!